# a native exception occurred during launch for julia in the latest version of vscode

Tags: exception, terminal, julia, arguments

It always displays (args[3] must be a string (not a undefined)).However, I don't know which file does args appear in .

I don't know if anyone has encountered the same problem and has solved it? I tried to modify the launch.json file, but it didn't work.